# Forwarding to error line in Jupyter on Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

Hello i am using Jupyterlab and Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda to program via Python 3. When getting an error message it tells me the location where the error occurred and what kind of error, so far so good. Is there a way i can click the message or something like that so it forwards me to the error line instead of having to scroll myself? With small code this is no problem but when the code is getting much it´s rather inconvenient. Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Use PyCharm IDE for that. Pycharm gives a link to the line where there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter is not an actual IDE, even though it has a lot of functionality and extensions. You will need to use an actual IDE like Pycharm or Spyder.

Comment: ok thanks i'll look inot Spyder and Pycharm, allthough a bummer since Jupyterlab is quite nice to use imo.